# How do I create a basic class and instance of that class in Forth?

Tags: class, oop, object, forth, gforth

I would like to create an object to represent some electrical readings, such as input voltage. To do this, I want to create a basic class structure to handle different types of readings -- say, current as well as voltage.

The pseudo-code (well, Python actually) for what I want to do is this:

```
# Create base class as a subclass of a common class to all other classes
class PowerReading(object):
    # Defining word to  initialize instance variables using the given input
    def __init__(self, current_value, units):
        # instance variables 
        self.value = current_value
        self.units = units

# Define new class based on our generic class above
class Voltage(PowerReading):
    # Call the parent class word with an input value, and constant units string 
    def __init__(self, current_value):
        super(Voltage, self).__init__(current_value, 'volts')

# Create another class based on the same parent class as Voltage 
class Current(PowerReading):
    def __init__(self, current_value):
        # Call the parent word with current units
        super(Voltage, self).__init__(current_value, 'amps')

# input_voltage_atod() is defined elsewhere: gives an instant reading
# from the ATOD pin on the power input rail, already converted to units of volts.

# Create instance object variable using our new Voltage class. 
input_voltage = Voltage(input_voltage_atod())
# Use the object's instance variables
print input_voltage.value, input_voltage.units
# 3.25 volts
```

I'm using `Gforth` and the `oof.fs` extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some simple gforth symbols:

```
: symbol ( "name" -- )
  create lastxt , does> ( -- xt ) @ ;
: .symbol ( xt -- )
  >name name>string 1 /string type ;

symbol 'volts
symbol 'amps
```

Here's an oof.fs equivalent of your Python:

```
require oof.fs

object class power-reading
  float var value
  cell var units
  method .
how:
  : init ( r-value units -- )  units !  value f! ;
  : . ( -- ) value f@ f.  units @ .symbol space ;
class;

power-reading class voltage
how:
  : init ( r-value -- )  'volts super init ;
class;

power-reading class current
how:
  : init ( r-value -- )  'amps super init ;
class;

3.25e voltage : input-voltage
input-voltage .  \ Output: 3.25 volts
```

That's pretty similar, isn't it?

These days I use mini-oof2.fs, which is much lower level than oof.fs,
and which does a lot less.  In that:

```
object class
  ffield: value
  field: units
  method init ( value units -- )
  method show ( -- )
end-class power-reading

[: ( r-value units -- )  units !  value f! ;] power-reading to init
[: ( -- ) value f@ f.  units @ .symbol space ;] power-reading to show

power-reading class
end-class voltage

[: ( r-value -- )  value f! 'volts units ! ;] voltage to init

power-reading class
end-class current

[: ( r-value -- )  value f! 'amps units ! ;] current to init

voltage new constant input-voltage
3.25e input-voltage .init
input-voltage .show  \ Output: 3.25 volts
```

The `[: ... ;]` aren't special mini-oof2.fs syntax.  They're just
gforth quotations, used here as synonyms of :NONAME .

The `.init` and `.show` macro-expand (sort of) into `>o init o>`
and `>o show o>`, respectively.

Rather than have an INIT method, I often have a non-OO word that
constructs the object:

```
: >current ( r -- o )
  current new >o  value f!  'amps units !  o o> ;
: current, ( r -- )
  here >o [ current >osize @ ]L allot  value f!  'amps units !  o> ;
```

But of course this doesn't play as well with complex object orientation
and SUPER methods and such.  It's a 90% solution as opposed to the 100%
OO solutions provided by oof.fs and SWOOP and FMS.

Comment: Badass answer! The `oof.fs` example works flawlessly and does exactly what I'm looking for. The use of gforth symbols is nice, too. I appreciate the `mini-oof2.fs` example, but I can't get the `[: ... ;]` syntax to work (`:10: Undefined word, >>>[:<<<...`). Are these synonyms you defined or built-in to gforth? FYI I used `require mini-oof.fs` (`require mini-oof2.fs` backtraced).

Comment: @CivFan, they're built-in, and provided by default, but you may need a newer version of gforth to have them.  I'm using gforth on Android, which is sort of bleeding edge.  mini-oof.fs definitely won't work with that code: it doesn't use `>o o o>` and friends, for example.